# Using Markdown2 with Django

Tags: python, django, markdown

I have never asked a question here before, please bear with me. I am working on a wiki project that has a requirement to convert markdown files using markdown2.

```
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "content": markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(title)), "title": title
    })
```

Above is how I pass it to the HTML page and it renders on the page with the proper HTML tags, but it doesn't seem to use them. Below is how it appears on the browser.

```
              <pre><code>      # HTML
</code></pre>

<p>HTML is a markup language that can be used to define the structure of a web page. HTML elements include</p>

<ul>
<li>headings</li>
<li>paragraphs</li>
<li>lists</li>
<li>links</li>
<li>and more!
most recent major version of HTML is HTML5.</li>
</ul>
```

I am passing it directly to a Django template with the safe filter included as shown below.

```
  <textarea name="content" rows="5" cols="50" readonly>
              {{ content|safe }}
         </textarea><br>
```

Thank you ahead of time, I hope I provided enough information to make my problem clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like your content is going inside a `<textarea>` form field...that's going to prevent the browser from interpreting the HTML and just show exactly what is passed over.

Change to a `<div>` or something and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! Once i took it out of the <textarea> it worked great.